# gnu.io и и org.apache.commons.logging для проекта Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

пытаюсь построить готовый проект на своем компьютере, но не выходит: не распознаются классы  вот этих зависимостей - gnu.io и org.apache.commons.logging  (подчеркиваются строчки import).

Подозреваю, что где-то просто не прописаны связи... 
Подскажите, где их нужно добавить?

Comment: `build.gradle` покажите